# Bootstrap grid with both equivalent table rowspan and colspan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a layout like this one in bootstrap3

[image]

Found something similar here but not able to make it work:

https://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/52/

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="well">1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div></div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">2</div></div>
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">3</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">4</div></div>
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">5</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is still for Bootstrap 2. That's not going to fly at all. I suggest you convert to [proper version 3 syntax](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options) and see where that gets you. You need an outer row with three columns, and you need  two rows nested in the first column containing one and two columns, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a nested grid

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">


  <div class="row mx-auto" style="height: 200px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="row "> <!-- nested row 1 -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 "> <!-- nested quick links col -->
          AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        </div>

        <div class="row"> <!-- nested row 2 -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            BBBBBBB
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            CCCCCCCCC
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3"> DDDDDD </div>

  </div>
</div>
```